# How to add an external configuration file in Vue + Vite app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-cli

I'm trying to migrate my Vue 2 + Vue CLI project to Vue 3 with Vite. I'm wondering if it is possible to let to a Vite to read an external config file placed in public folder which store configuration for Web API. I tried and failed.
The below configuration works fine. Once built and deployed to IIS server it allows you to swap the domain and port with the selected ones. I don't think I can achieve this effect using environment variables.

Here is my working code from a Vue 2 application that I am trying to migrate:

File structure:

```
public
- config
-- config.js
- index.html
src
- axios.config
vue.config.js
```

**config.js**

```js
const appConfig = {
  BASE_URI: 'http://localhost:15752',
  TOKEN_ITEM_NAME: 'access_token'
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="config/config.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**axios.config.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import appConfig from 'appConfig'
import devextremeAjax from 'devextreme/core/utils/ajax'

const baseDomain = appConfig.BASE_URI <-- HAS CORRECT VALUE 'http://localhost:15752'
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api`
const tokenItemName = appConfig.TOKEN_ITEM_NAME
const token = localStorage.getItem(tokenItemName)
```

**vue.config.js**

```js
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      minimize: false
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".wasm", ".mjs", ".js", ".vue", ".json"]
    },
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        dry: true,      
      })
    ]
  },
  publicPath: "./",
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .loader("vue-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        //modify the options...
        return options;
      });
    config.externals({
      appConfig: "appConfig"
    });
  },
};
```

**This is what I tried:**

Files structure:

```
public
- config
-- config.js
src
- axios.config
index.html
vite.config.js
```

No changes to **config.js**.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/config/config.js"></script> <-- PATH CHANGED
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**axios.config.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import appConfig from 'appConfig' <-- NOT WORKING (UNDEFINED)

const test = window['appConfig']  <-- NOT WORKING (UNDEFINED)

const baseDomain = appConfig.BASE_URI <-- UNDEFINED
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api`
const tokenItemName = appConfig.TOKEN_ITEM_NAME
const token = localStorage.getItem(tokenItemName)
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { viteExternalsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-externals'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    viteExternalsPlugin(
      {
        appConfig: 'appConfig'
      }
    )
  ],
  server: {
    port: 8080
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    }
  },
})
```

I tried to replace

```js
config.externals({
  appConfig: "appConfig"
});
```

with:

```js
viteExternalsPlugin({
  appConfig: 'appConfig'
})
```

Result: runtime error BASE_URI is undefined in axios file.

Any solutions?